# print values of column 1 when values of another one are different from NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is easier than what I think, but I'm struggling. 
I have 3 columns,

```
1. Name: (a,b,c,d)

2. City/Birth: (w,x,y,z)

3. City/Current :(q,t,y,z)
```

I need to print the names of people when City/Birth is the same as City/Current.

Expected output: `c,d`

So far I applied lowercase, created a new column named "match" and I have like 300 "NaNs" and just "20" matches (where "Birth" and "current" are the same) with:

```
df['match'] = np.where((df['birth'] == df['current']), df['birth'], np.nan)
```

I'm just struggling to print the names of those 20 matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['birth'] == df['current'],'Name']
```